# React native runs slow on ios device when remote debugger is off

Tags: react-native

I run into this issue when try to run app on ios device(ipad4,ios10).
The app runs slow on device when remote debugger is off, if remote js debugger is on, then it runs pretty fine.
I also tried `react-native run-ios --configuration Release`, but its still slow. Don't know what's going on here.
Any idea how can I evaluate the real performance of the app ?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Try to change the scheme in xcode: Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Run -> Set Build configuration to Release.

[image]

Comment: I guess `react-native run-ios --configuration Release` should do the same thing ? It still runs slower than have remote debugger on in dev mode.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue and my problem was that I was doing some extra console.log calls into the render methods and it was slowing everything down because of that. See if you have these in your code, remove them and try to run it again.

The problem was the same, with the debugger everything run great (I assume the logs were removed) and without debugger I saw the logs running in xCode. You can check the same in the console logs that are shown in xCode when you connect a simulator or device to your machine. In there, I was seeing a huge JSON object being logged every few seconds and then the log froze for some time.

Comment: you save my 3 days :)

Comment: Downvote for not explaining this _and without debugger I saw the logs running in xCode._

Comment: @Green Really? Do I also need to explain how to develop in RN? In xCode you see the console and device logs, that is pretty much what I meant. I appreciate that you at least explained the downvote but it is a little too far fetch. I will add the explaination in the answer

Answer (score 0):

It's not a solution to your problem (I really hope for you, your problem is solved in the meantime, but I'm still posting this answer if anyone else is having this problem).

As written in this [github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8327), when you run your app with a debugger, the JS thread lives in your debugger and not in your app. This means if you're using for example the chrome debugger, your JS get executed with the google V8 VM and the speed of your Browser/Computer. Make sure to disable every debug option and switch to release mode when you do a performance test.

If you still have performance problems you have to look and analyze other things.

Comment: This is ridiculous. When RN runs on Linux debugger is very fast